# While trying to host a strapi app on Render, I'm getting the following error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432

Tags: node.js, postgresql, hosting, render, strapi

The postgres database is currently running on Render, and the project is running fine locally, but I'm having issues after "strapi start" runs on Render.

```
==> Running 'npm start'
> server@0.1.0 start
> strapi start
[2023-12-31 21:56:17.339] debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2023-12-31 21:56:17.340] error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16)
```

```
Here is my .env
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=1337
APP_KEYS=jP8pb1lYsAhnmURarewxhA==,34xnLMYHY5jiU7ONTstTqQ==
API_TOKEN_SALT=e4f87d7f08bb790eb62de7fd31c3b2a8
ADMIN_JWT_SECRET=tobemodified
TRANSFER_TOKEN_SALT=tobemodified
JWT_SECRET=tobemodified
DATABASE_URL=postgres://ecommerce_5hx0_user:CtwnCSvdGjy0YEklEqjmIY5q1aCDaCSk@dpg-cm8cg3fqd2ns73dgo9h0-a/ecommerce_5hx0
DATABASE_CLIENT=postgres
DATABASE_HOST=dpg-cm8cg3fqd2ns73dgo9h0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=ecommerce_5hx0
DATABASE_USERNAME=ecommerce_5hx0_user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=CtwnCSvdGjy0YEklEqjmIY5q1aCDaCSk
CLOUDINARY_NAME =dr9gnuvml
CLOUDINARY_KEY =863949315549128
CLOUDINARY_SECRET =y2EfOFt00Jw1IaPf1PlEoGTq3hA
```

and databse.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
connection: {
  client: 'postgres',
    connection: {
      connectionString: env('DATABASE_URL'),
      host: env('DATABASE_HOST'),
      port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT'),
      database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
      user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
      password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', true),
    },
  },
});
```

I tried using different strings for the DATABASE_HOST. I also tried not having a DATABASE_URL in the database.js and .env